# Generate consecutive number in CosmoDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using CosmoDB to store my data. The ID is a GUID. There is a new requirement to display a consecutive number. How to achive that in a document based db? I want to keep GUID as "id" and have another unique field "display_id". The application is running in a "App Service". I do not want to run a SQL-Server with a "serial table".

Answer (score 1):

There's no such facility built-in to provide you with increasing numbers. That will be up to you to manage in your app layer (or potentially in a Cosmos DB stored procedure).

Also: There is nothing specific to document databases and increasing numbers. It's simply something that isn't offered via the database engine.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I was thinking to manage that via the app layer and using a SQL-Server.I do not want to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut. How it would looks like to use a cosmo db stored procedure for that?